# Incrementing date in a loop with php

Tags: php, api, loops, date, increment

I am new to coding in php and I have a query about getting a date to increment in a loop which is produced by a call to a weather API (http://openweathermap.org), I am using PHP curl which returns XML and I then am looping through 3 sets of data for 3 days, the first day is the current day and then the following two are the next 2 consecutive dates.

I thought the simplest way would be to save the current date and then increment this date everytime the code loops, like this:

```
if($numOfItems>0){ // yes, some items were retrieved

        foreach($items as $current){  //open loop
        ?>
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;position:relative;padding:2%" class="WeatherSection">
        <?php

        $myDate = date('d/m/Y');
        echo $myDate;
        var $day = date('d++');
        $day = 'd';

        $summary = $current->symbol['name'];
        echo "<p>$summary</p>";
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        }  //close loop

    }  //close code
```

?>

Sadly this doesn't seem to work,I'm sure for someone with more PHP experience this is a simple fix but I just can't figure out why this won't work... much appreciate any guidance!

EDITED: thank you for your help, I tried adding this code:

```
$time = time();
        echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
        $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
        echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
```

But it displays all these dates 3 times as it loops, see the screenshot...
I just want the date to display once, increment for the next loop and display again with the new date and then once again. Is there a simple way to do this?

[Screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HicP.jpg)

EDITED: After looking into options, it seems that trying to gather the date from the XML might be the best option, the way the PHP curl gathers the data though, it seems I can't get to the data in 'time'. Here's my new code:

```
<?php
```

$request = //this is where my API key is added, have removed for putting on StackOverflow

```
$crl = curl_init(); // creating a curl object
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$xml_to_parse = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl); // closing the curl object

$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_to_parse);

// traversing the xml nodes to count how many days were retrieved
// ignore the first one (weatherdata)
$items = $parsed_xml->forecast->time; 
$numOfItems = count($items);

if($numOfItems>0){ // yes, some items were retrieved

        foreach($items as $current){  //open loop

        ?>
        <div style="width:30%;float:left;position:relative;padding:1.5%;margin-top:10px;text-align:center;" class="WeatherSection">
        <?php

        $dateofweather = strval($current->time['day']); //my attempt to retrieve data from the XML
        echo "<p>$dateofweather</p>";

        $summary = $current->symbol['name'];

        echo "<p>$summary</p>";
        $icon = $current->symbol['var'];
        echo "<p><img src='http://localhost:8888/images/weathericons/$icon.png'/></p>";

        $rain = intval($current->precipitation['value']);
        if($rain > 5) { echo "<div class='orange_background'><h5 style='padding:10px'>Very Rainy! Remember to regularly get your roof checked!</h5></div>"; }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div style="width:1px;height:300px;float:left;position:relative;padding:0;margin:5px;margin-top:10px;background:#fff;"></div>
        <?php
        }  //close loop

    }  //close code
```

?>

Comment: It does have the date in the XML, but I couldn't seem to grab the data out of this. The data starts with <time day="2016-03-25"> and ends with </time>,  I can grab data from the syntax that is held inbetween these but I can't seem to grab that data from this initial time syntax.

Comment: Ah, ok! I'll post the XML up in the main question.. :)

Comment: I couldn't post it here, but here's a screenshot of the XML data -
http://www.emilyfraser.co.uk/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Thank for that - I will get the data  - signed up with them - this looks like fun :)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I've looked into the GitHub link but implementing that is possibly beyond my capabilities at the moment. Ideally it would be great if I could access the XML syntax where it holds the data for the date, I'll update my code so it's maybe clearer how it's set up. I only took a section of the code I have in the initial post... really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I have added the new code in the post, who would have thought it would be so tricky getting a couple dates displaying? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Ryan, a simple loop on the date is working now. Thanks for all your help, will definitely need to look into more stuff on parsing XML as it's all very new to me!

Comment: Was helpful for me :) Glad to assist. Thanks for introducing me to this - is fun :) I would not have known about but for being here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to use `date('d') + 1` in function `mktime`, but it's better to use `strtotime` instead..

```
$time = time();
echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
$time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
```

**update**

```
$time = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo date( 'd/m/Y', $time);
    $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how would I get the code to output the incremented date the next time it loops though? At the moment that displays the current date and tomorrow's date, but it displays both those dates 3 times as the code loops rather than it outputing: today's date, tomorrow's date, the next day's date.

Comment: Thank you for the update, that's working now, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$my_date = time();
echo date( 'd/m/Y', $my_date);
$my_date += (24 * 3600); // 24 hours of 3600 seconds
$day = date( 'd', $my_date );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mktime function:

```
$today = mktime(0, 0, 1, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$today_date = date('d/m/Y', $today);

$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 1, date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y'));
$tomorrow_date = date('d/m/Y', $tomorrow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php object [add function](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

or in procedural

```
$date = date_create('2016-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```